# Convert assembly to C using Replace some groups with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, c, regex, assembly

I want to convert asm to c(assembly to C)
I saw http://www.textmaestro.com/InfoEx_17_Convert_Assembly.htm 
(please the page)
page on web and easily after that i try to Do this job using  find and Replace with Regex in C#

i am not computer field student so i am not professional at Regex.
I am working 5 days and after this time now i know that i cant do this.i wrote very code but without any success
sample program:
mov r1,1;
mov r2,2;
convert to :
r1=1;
r2=2;
please help me to do this correctly

Comment: You cannot create a program that converts assembly to C unless your sole intention is to have it work on one specific compiler and you don't care that it will break if the compiler is updated (or even if different flags are used to affect the output). You can try, but bear in mind that insane asylums have special rooms for people that do.

Answer (score 3):

OP has (painfully) learned that regexps are not a good solution to problems that involve analysis or translation of software. Processing strings simply is not the same as building context-sensitive analyses of text with complex structure.

People keep re-learning this lesson.  It is true that you can use repeated regex to simulate Post rewriting systems, and Post systems, being Turing capable, can technically do anything.  It is also true that nobody really wants to, or more importantly, nobody can write a very complex program for a real Turing machine [or an equivalent Post system]. This is why we have all these other computer languages and tools.  [The TextMaestro system to which OP refers is trying to be exactly that Post system.]

However, the task he wants to do is possible and practical with the proper tools: [program transformation systems (PTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).

In particular, he should see this technical paper for a description of precisely how this has been done with one particular PTS: See [Pigs from sausages? Reengineering from assembler to C via FermaT transformations](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1034998).  Such a tool in effect is a custom compiler from assembly source code to the target language, and includes parsing, name (label) resolution, often data flow analysis and complex code generation and optimization.  A PTS is used because they make it relatively easy to build that kind of compiler. This tool has been used for at least Intel assembly to C, and mainframe (System 360/370/Z) assembly to C, for large-scale tasks.  (I have no relationship to this tool but do have huge respect for the authors).

The naysayers in the comments seem to think this is impossible to do except for extremely constrained circumstances.   It is true that the more one knows about the assembly code in terms of idioms, the somewhat easier this gets, but the technical approach in the paper is not limited to specific compiler output by any means.  It is also true that truly arcane assembler code (especially self-modifying or having runtime code generation) is extremely difficult to translate.